# Antiderivative of $e^{au}$

Tags: integration

I cannot seem to figure out $\int e^{au}du$.  I have tried u-substitution (of course with a variable other than u) and can't get it to work out to the right answer.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Reverse chain rule, one antiderivative is $e^{au}/a$ assuming you are integrating wrt $u$ of course.

Comment: I don't get it. What are you trying to integrate?. $\int e^{au}du$ or $\int e^{a}u du$ or something else?.
For the first one, try the substitution $x=au$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice $$d(e^{au}) = a e^{au} du \implies \int d(e^{au}) = \int a e^{au} du \implies \int e^{au} du = \frac{1}{a} e^{au} + K$$

Answer (score -1):

$$\frac d{du}\left(\frac1ae^{au}\right)=e^{au}$$

Comment: @Lemur...No me acostumbro a este nick...

Comment: jajajajaja ! :P

Comment: @DonAntonio: Can you show me the steps taken for differentiating this particular equation?  I keep getting the wrong answer on this as well.

Comment: @Ethan, chain rule: put $\;f(u)=e^u\;,\;\;g(u):=au\;$ , so $$e^{au}=f(g(u))\implies (e^{au})'=f'(g(u))\cdot g'(u)=e^{g(u)}\cdot a=ae^{au}$$and from here the solution...

Comment: @DonAntonio: Shouldnt $g'(u)$ be $(u+a)$ by the product rule?

Comment: No @Ethan: $\;(a+u)'=a'+u'=0+1=1\;$ , since $\;a\;$ is a constant...

Comment: @DonAntonio: Ah, okay, since your taking the derivative with respect to $u$, $u$ is your variable, correct?

Comment: Of course, @Ethat...that's the way **you** defined things.